# Responsive Carousel Issue with 767px Media Query - Carousel Left/Right Button and Btn Button Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries, carousel

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my site: http://www.boriskdesign.com

Everything is perfect, except at 767px (smartphone size), the Carousel's left and right buttons aren't clickable. Same goes for the Yellow button that says "Contact Me."

What's going on?

Here's the code for the 767 Media Query:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .container {
    margin-bottom: 60%;
  }

  div.footer_right_border {
  border-right: none;
  }

  div.footer_right_border {
      visibility: none;
  }

  .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    margin-top: -13%;
  }

  .navbar-inner {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin: -20px;
  }
  .carousel {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-top: 7%;
  }

  .carousel .container {
    padding-top: 20px;       
  }

  .carousel .item {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel img {
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .carousel-caption .lead,
  .carousel-caption .btn {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .btn-custom {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 19;
  }
  .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .featurette .lead {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

}
```

The code for the Carousel:

```
<!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/carousel/all_devices.jpg" style="opacity: .9;"   class="img_car">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Responsive Web Design</h1>
              <p class="lead">For all devices under the sun.</p>
              <br><br><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-custom" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/carousel/rn.jpg" alt="" class="img_car">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>The Rita & Naum Orchestra</h1>
              <p class="lead">Website for the Russian-American band.</p>
              <br><br><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-custom" href="web.html">Browse Gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/carousel/mrk.jpg" alt="" class="img_car">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Mr. K Tutoring</h1>
              <p class="lead">Made with Twitter Bootstrap Responsive.</p>
              <br><br><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-custom" href="web.html">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/carousel/rf.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>DJ Ricky Flood</h1>
              <p class="lead">Website for the new, hot New York DJ.</p>
              <br><br><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-custom" href="web.html">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your carousel controls are functioning properly, but they are underneath a div. I quickly defined a z-index on your left and right carousel-control to get them working.

Comment: Thanks, dude, that worked. Putting the z-indexes in there totally wonked out their margins, so I had to put in a "pull-right" and "pull-left" class, as well as decrease the top margins, but it worked great. :D